# JSON schema: schemas in types

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to create a complex JSON schema that tries to use conditional dependencies without having access to OneOf, AnyOf etc

I am basically trying to combine

```
const schema1 = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        q1: {
            type: "boolean",
            enum: [false]
        }
    },
    required: ["q1"]
}
```

and

```
const schema2 = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        q1: {
            type: "boolean",
            enum: [true]
        }
        sq1: {
            type: "boolean"
        }
    },
    required: ["q1", "sq1"]
}
```

into one schema `combined_schema` thus mocking the conditional dependency requiring an answer for `sq1` if the answer for `q1` was true.

In the JSON schema wiki I was reading that AnyOf would replace the "schema" in types" but looking at the example I am unsure of how that could be used in a specific case (The {"schema1": "here"} part is very confusing.

https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/anyOf,-allOf,-oneOf,-not

Could anybody please help me apply the wiki example to my real world problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. They key is using `refs`

```
{
    "type": [
                {"$ref": "#/schema1"},
                {"$ref": "#/schema2"}
            ],
    "schema2":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "q1": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "enum": [true]
            },
            "sq1": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        },
    "required": ["q1", "sq1"]
    },
    "schema1": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "q1": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "enum": [false]
            }
        },
        "required": ["q1"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to work with older jsonSchema libs too. This is the right answer. In an older version of jsonSchema, you had to use a list in the `type` property. The "$ref" is optional.

Answer (score 1):

The schema your answer is not a valid JSON-schema. You can do it with anyOf keyword:

```
{
    type: "object",
    required: ["q1"]
    anyOf: [
        {
            properties: {
                q1: { enum: [false] } // no need for type here
            }
        },
        {
            properties: {
                q1: { enum: [true] },
                sq1: { type: "boolean" }
            },
            required: ["sq1"]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is also the keyword [switch](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#switch-v5-proposal) from JSON-Schema v5 proposals implemented in [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) (Disclaimer: I created it).

Comment: anyOf is out of the question as clearly stated in my question.

Comment: The only alternative is v5 switch then... Why do you need to avoid anyOf?